# SpringBoot library project does not see main app properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, properties-file

I have a setup like this:

1. Main SpringBoot project with application-default.properties which on our deployment server are partially overwritten by a deployment specific properties.
2. Shared SpringBoot library project which has its own properties.

And when I run my main project with the library project attached (via gradle sourceControl gitRepository) I can see that the properties in the library project are empty.

How can I make the library project use the properties passed down from the main application ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge properties, please consider this [official page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

## Option 1 - default properties in library

As I found previously (probably, it is fixed), if you have jar1 and jar2 (sorted alphabetically) and both of them have `application.properties` file, only first will be used. They aren't merged. So please be carefully there.

However you can use [@PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) in your library, e.g. put default properties there into the custom file name (for example - `defaults-for-jar2.properties` or something like this, to avoid automatic loading by Spring).

In this case:

1. Property load logic outside of your library will be the same with current.
2. Your library will load file from [@PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) and next they will be overridden (if you have this) by your application.

## Option 2 - configuration properties

If you use Kotlin and Spring, you can use [ConfigurationProperties](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/#_configuration_properties). And you can define the default values there. Moreover, IntelliJ Idea will highlight the default and possible values (according to the type, because you can use not only String, but any custom `enum class`, `Duration` class, etc.).

Just from that link:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("blog")
data class BlogProperties(var title: String, val banner: Banner) {
  data class Banner(val title: String? = null, val content: String)
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BlogProperties::class)
class BlogApplication {
  // ...
}
```

Please note:

1. You should mention your settings data class in the library configuration.
2. You should configure kapt properly to have Intelli Sence in IDEs.

Comment: I tried the first solution and renamed the properties file to 'common.properties' and annotated the main class to use that as "@PropertySource". But still then I run the code from the main application I can see that the bean from the library is not initialized (I assume that the @Value is not discoverered and autowired properly)

Comment: @darkhie, could you please try something like ```@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")``` from https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/? I forget the right notation, however if you want to see into the jars you have to add ```classpath``` prefix.